# string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#

tengo este codigo para cargar a un TextBox el ultimo dato de la Base de datos y sumarle 1 para llevar un conteo de usuarios

```
private void generaidusuario()
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT TOP 1 Id_usuario FROM Tab_usuarios ORDER BY Id_usuario DESC";
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, cn);
            cn.Open();
            string codmax = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
            int cod = Convert.ToInt32(codmax) + 1; //aqui me da error la conversion//
            txtidempleado.Text = Convert.ToString(cod);
            cn.Close();

        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Revisaste que la variable `codmax` contiene una cadena que se pueda convertir en un entero?

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa si, el campo Id_usuario es INT en la base de datos

Comment: Me refiero a la variable que creas `string codmax`, te fijaste si en realidad tiene un entero, o lo que devuelve el `convert` es un entero, porque `ExecuteScalar`devuelve es un objecto, el cual se castea al valor que uno nesecita.

Comment: @OrlandoDeLaRosa Ah bien ya entendi y ya encontre la solucion muchas gracias hermano. Era que estaba declarando la variable codmax como string cuando realmente necesitaba un Int por que es lo que me esta devolviendo el ExecuteScalar y tambien estaba convirtiendo innecesariamente la variable codmax a Int32 cuando ya era tipo Int